# What config file applies to edit this line: Main PID: 675992 (/usr/sbin/ seen when invoking systemctl status apache2)?

Tags: server, apache2

Headless server 22.04.2
I have what appears to be a typo when I invoke `systemctl status apache2` I get this:

```
_________________________________________________________________
 systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-03-04 08:56:03 EST; 8h ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
   Main PID: 675992 (/usr/sbin/apach)
      Tasks: 56 (limit: 2283)
     Memory: 26.1M
        CPU: 8.882s
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─675992 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─675993 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─675994 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─675995 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
____________________________________________________
```

where Main PID: 675992 (/usr/sbin/apach) appears wrong to me. Shouldn't apach be apache or apache2? I may of made a typo when it setting up. If so - how do I edit it?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you also show us the output of `cat /proc/675992/comm` please? Replace 675992 with the current Main PID, if you have restarted the server in the meantime. Is this a bare-metal server, or some kind of container?

Comment: Steeldriver - My output of cat /proc/675992/comm is: /usr/sbin/apach and PID is the same, its a bare metal server.

Comment: Steeldriver - Based on your previous comment I found the file, but its live, any edits are immediately overwritten,  your auto truncate suggestion makes sense. Maybe its not an error at all...  I'm trying to get a cgi script working again after a move from a bsd server to a deb server. Paths are very different.

Comment: So... where my question was leading is that so far as I can see, the process name in `Main PID: 675992 (/usr/sbin/apach)` is populated by reading `/proc/<Main PID>/comm`, and that's why it's truncated (to 15 characters + newline) - see the section `/proc/[pid]/comm` in `man proc`. **However** everything I've read says that in general `/proc/<PID>/comm` contains the process basename, and indeed that's what I see for `apache2` on my 22.04 VM. So the more interesting question is why your system writes the full path to the comm file.

Comment: ... either way, it's unlikely to be any kind of mis-configuration of the apache2 server on your part

Comment: ... actually think I may have found the culprit - have you installed `mod_perl` (libapache2-mod-perl2)?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell - I find only this:                                                                         perl   5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1    amd64        
perl-base  5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1   amd64                                                                    
perl-modules-5.34      5.34.0-3ubuntu1.1

Comment: so nothing from `a2query -m perl` ?

Comment: This: perl (enabled by maintainer script)
Sorry I'm having confusion about how to interact jere! Newbie.  Is mod-perl the same as perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

No, you didn't make a typo when setting up the apache2 server. The process name is not read from a configuration file, it is read from the `/proc/[pid]/comm` kernel interface, and the truncation occurs there.

It appears to be a particular apache2 module, `mod_perl`, that is responsible for replacing the basename `apache2` with the (truncated) path `/usr/sbin/apach`.

### Details

The `systemctl status` command reads the process name from the kernel's process information pseudo-filesystem at `/proc/[pid]/comm` where the process ID `[pid]` is the apache2 `Main PID`. You can verify this by running `systemctl status apache2` under `strace`, for example:

```
$ systemctl show -P MainPID apache2.service
6525
$ strace -P /proc/6525/comm -e trace=%file,read,write systemctl --no-pager status apache2 >/dev/null
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/6525/comm", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(4, "/usr/sbin/apach\n", 1024)      = 16
read(4, "", 1024)                       = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You can see that it's reading the string `/usr/sbin/apach\n`, a total of 16 characters including the terminating newline `\n`. That length limit is imposed by the kernel `TASK_COMM_LEN` parameter, as noted in `man proc`:

> ```
> /proc/[pid]/comm (since Linux 2.6.33)
>       This  file exposes the process's comm value—that is, the command
>       name associated with the process.  Different threads in the same
>       process   may   have   different  comm  values,  accessible  via
>       /proc/[pid]/task/[tid]/comm.   A  thread  may  modify  its  comm
>       value,  or  that of any of other thread in the same thread group
>       (see the discussion of CLONE_THREAD in clone(2)), by writing  to
>       the   file   /proc/self/task/[tid]/comm.   Strings  longer  than
>       TASK_COMM_LEN (16) characters (including  the  terminating  null
>       byte) are silently truncated.
>       This  file  provides  a superset of the prctl(2) PR_SET_NAME and
>       PR_GET_NAME operations, and is employed by pthread_setname_np(3)
>       when used to rename threads other than the caller.  The value in
>       this file  is  used  for  the  %e  specifier  in  /proc/sys/ker‐
>       nel/core_pattern; see core(5).
> ```

If you look at almost any other process, you will see that its `/proc/[pid]/comm` file contains just the program's basename. The 16-character `TASK_COMM_LEN` value suggests it is not intended to contain path components - and indeed if you install a basic `apache2` server, that's exactly what you see. So what is changing it to `/usr/sbin/apach`?

Summoning up some google-fu, it turns out the answer is [mod_perl](https://perl.apache.org/). Specifically, in this comment on [Red Hat Bugzilla – Bug 782369](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=782369#c16)

> A process can call prctl(PR_SET_NAME) to set it's task name (task->comm) in the kernel, as long as the name is under 16 characters.  If you have mod_perl included in httpd, it calls prctl and sets the name to '/usr/sbin/httpd'.
>
> Why it does this, I have absolutely no clue.  But it does.

("httpd" is what RedHat calls apache2). If you're running apache2 in a testing environment, you can verify that's the culprit by temporarily disabling the mod_perl module:

```
sudo a2dismod perl
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

and you should see the process name in the `systemctl status` output revert back to `(apache2)`. You can re-enable the mod afterwards with

```
sudo a2enmod perl
```

and restarting the service again.

Comment: Probably this https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/mod_perl/blob/f31/f/mod_perl-short-name.patch should explain the why ... If I am not mistaken.

Comment: Steeldriver- Wow! That's deep! Apache is voo doo... Is this something I need to "fix" to get my perl cgiScript.pl to work? Thanks for all your time.

Comment: @Raffa good find yes that looks like it might be it

Comment: Thank you Steeldriver and Raffa - My horizon has been expanded...